# charAt values of a string (converted from integer) matching although they are different

Tags: java

hoping for some help.  I converted an integer to a string to match the characters but although they don't match, it appears to be returning a true value.  The whole idea is to see if the integer is a palindrome.  Please see my code below.  Not sure why, I think it's a fairly simple error I'm making somewhere. I'm fairly new so any help is appreciated :)  The method has to be specific to the way it's named below.

```
public static int reverse(int number)
    {
        String strnumber=Integer.toString(number);
        boolean result;

            for(int i=1;i<=strnumber.length()/2;i++)
            {
                char ch = strnumber.charAt(i-1);
                System.out.println(ch);
                char ch2 =strnumber.charAt(strnumber.length()-i);
                System.out.println(ch2);

                if(strnumber.charAt(i-1)==strnumber.charAt(strnumber.length()-i))
                {
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

        if(result = true)
        {
            System.out.println("The integer is a palindrome.");
        }
        else if(result = false)
        {
            System.out.println("The integer is not a palindrome.");
        }

        return number;
```

Comment: One `=` is assignment. Use `if (result)` and `else`

Comment: Your method is called `reverse`, but you check if the number is palindrome, then simply return the number...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(result = true)` and `else if(result = false)`, assigns value to result, not comparing. `=` is assignment operator, the compare operator is `==`

Change the following lines:

```
    if(result = true)
    {
        System.out.println("The integer is a palindrome.");
    }
    else if(result = false)
    {
        System.out.println("The integer is not a palindrome.");
    }
```

**TO**

```
    if(result == true)
    {
        System.out.println("The integer is a palindrome.");
    }
    else if(result == false)
    {
        System.out.println("The integer is not a palindrome.");
    }
```

Comment: Could also be `if(result)` and `if(!result)`

Comment: Yes, it can be. also can be `if(result)` and `else`